# PHP Update giving error if no data is edited

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Thanks for asking me to make my question clearer.

I have a form which is used to save content in a database. 
The user is also allowed to update any content by editing the fields in the form and submitting it.

The update query looks something like this:-

```
$res = mysql_query("UPDATE freight SET .... WHERE id='$id'") or die ( mysql_error());
    if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
        //do some stuff 
        return true;    
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
```

Now my problem is this: If the user changes some field while updating the form, mysql_affected_rows() is > 0 so I am able to "//do some stuff". 
But if the user does not change any field in the form and simply submits, mysql_affected_rows return 0 and I reach the false block.

I was under the impression that UPDATE should overwrite every time thereby mysql_affected_rows() should return 1 irrespective of whether any fields have been changed or not.

I use the return value to display an appropriate success or error message in the screen. Hence this is a serious bug.

Can you suggest whats the right way to achieve the correct functionality?

Thanks,
Vish

Comment: MySQL does not consider it an error to run an update query that does not affect any rows (and it should not consider it an error).  Any errors being created are coming from either an invalid query or something happening in the PHP script.  To be able to help, we're going to need more information.

Comment: Could you post some code please ?*

Comment: Tags says nothing about mysql, no code... What update button? Mysql editor update button? Or an input type submit button? Without code your error could be everywhere....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mysql_affected rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) **-1** will be returned if the query itself can not be issued to the server, possibly because of syntax error AND if the last query was not either an INSERT or UPDATE statement.

> When using UPDATE, MySQL will not update columns where the new value
>   is the same as the old value. This creates the possibility that
>   mysql_affected_rows() may not actually equal the number of rows
>   matched, only the number of rows that were literally affected by the
>   query.

so your solution can be achieved by below logic ( but this is not safe)

```
if(mysql_affected_rows()!=-1){
}
```

Comment: Thank You @diEcho. It was really helpfull!
Can you please share from where you quoted the text in your response.

Comment: the link i have mentioned in first line

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $_POST['message'] != '' ) {
   // add the field to your query
} else { // this is optional
   // don't add it to your query
}

// do the mysql update here
```